# How is this product of tensors defined?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds, curvature, tensor

I am reading the paper “ The first eigenvalue of a small geodesic ball in a riemannian manifold”, by Karp and Pinsky, from where I took the following:

[image: product]

Here, $\Delta_{-2}$ denotes the usual Laplacian in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $R$ is the curvature tensor of the manifold and $\rho$ is defined by

$$ \rho(x) = \sum_{i,j} \rho_{ij} x_i x_j$$

where $\rho_{ij}$ are the components of the Ricci tensor of the manifold.

What does $R\#R$ mean? It should be a kind of product between $(4,0)$ tensors that outputs a function. Have you seen this before?

P.S. the reference they cite is not available online.

Comment: What's the reference?

Comment: Usually, what you end up doing is calculating it yourself. Any chance you tried that already?

Comment: The reference is: A. Gray, M. Pinsky. The mean exit time from a small geodesic ball in a riemannian manifold, Bulletin des Sciences Mathématiques, 2eme série 107(1983), 345-370.

Comment: a superscript # means "take the traceless part of the tensor" , perhaps the typed text did not allow for a superscript # ?